# How to wait for an element to be visible in CUCUBER JS?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am getting :

```
NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

My wait function is not waiting at all. As soon as it gets to that step it fails without waiting for the set wait time.

in my world.js i define my drive

```
var driver = buildChromeDriver();
  ...
  var World = function World() {
  ...
  this.driver = driver;
}
```

This is  on of my steps :

```
  this.Then(/^xxxxx$/, function () {
  this.driver.wait(function () {
      return this.driver.findElement({ xpath: props.woocomerceSelectors.viewCart }).isDisplayed();
  }, 4000);});
```

Answer (score 1):

The wait will loop through until a non-false answer is returned within the loop.

What your code is doing at the moment is returning a pending promise, which is not false, therefore will not loop through.

If you grab the stuff from this promise, and return whether it's equal to true, then you should have more luck.

```
this.Then(/^xxxxx$/, function () {
    this.driver.wait(function () {
        return this.driver.findElement({xpath: props.woocomerceSelectors.viewCart}).isDisplayed()
            .then(function (isDisplayed) {
                return isDisplayed == true;
            });
    }, 4000);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: just a thing. maybe i am doing somthing wrong but i am getting an error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'findElement' of undefined for the ( this.driver ) what do you think i am doing wrong?

Comment: A quick way of doing this, would be to use a global function.

`global.getDriver = function(){ return driver; }` in the world.js file should mean that in your step definition files you can have `var driver = getDriver()` and then you will no longer have to use `this.driver`, you'd simply be able to do `driver.wait`, `driver.findElement` etc.